# Can 'asking for duplicate confirm' be a better approach?

Tags: discussion

Looking at [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60292/how-to-create-outlines-for-objects-so-that-the-outlines-stays-when-the-file-is-e), for instance, I am wondering if we could proceed a bit differently :

- Ask the OP if it is a duplicate (that needs to be mentioned clearly as a question in the comments, for example "Can you confirm this is the same subject as [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50173/freestyle-is-not-exporting-with-the-object) ?")
- Let him/her 24 hours to give a reply (considering the timezones)
- Mark it as duplicate after this delay and explaining/commenting how to reopen it if he/she consider this is not a duplicate (if possible)

In my opinion, new BSE users can difficultly understand what is happening when their questions are closed.

I had recently a previous example where the OP indicated clearly that the link indicating a duplicate question was not an answer for him. But despite of that, his question has been closed... and so he deleted his question (this was about the pokeball if some remind it).

I don't know if the process indicated above is possible considering the vote mechanism. But I am quite sure that closing a question involves some kind of frustration (sometimes) that should be avoid. Ok, these kind of situations are obviously rare...

Comment: If a question doesn't have all the votes needed to close it as a duplicate, it will ask you if the proposed orginal question solved your problem. I think people won't see that very often because usually everyone agrees if a question is a duplicate or not. http://imgur.com/a/14nB6

Comment: @SammySwanson, ok thanks. I did not know that. But do I understand you well : this message can be seen only if the vote is not closed ?

Comment: I believe this is a bit about sensitivity. In the given example, I found it a bit too early to close the question as well, because the OP never mentioned 'Freestyle'. He was just looking for an idea on how to get outlines via DAE format to another software. I remember a tutorial where someone achieved this effect for the Blender Game Engine by creating an instance of his character, fiddling with shaders and normals, and displacing it out. A bit complicated, but it worked well. Maybe the moderators just need to give a question a little bit of time in such a case, and comment on the duplicate?

Comment: @lemon yes, the message can only be seen by the OP if the question has anywhere between 1-4 close votes (maybe 2-4). A question needs five to be closed as a duplicate.